# Как работает передаваемый параметр index в Points

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void LoadPoint(int index, DataRow_candle candle)
{
    if (index <= 0) return;
    if (index >= chart1.Series["Price"].Points.Count) return;
        
    double xval = chart1.Series["Price"].Points[index-1].XValue + 1;
    chart1.Series["Price"].Points[index].XValue = xval;
    chart1.Series["Price"].Points[index].YValues[0] = candle.high;
    chart1.Series["Price"].Points[index].YValues[1] = candle.low;
    chart1.Series["Price"].Points[index].YValues[3] = candle.open;
    chart1.Series["Price"].Points[index].YValues[2] = candle.close;
}
```

Бьюсь весь день, не могу понять, как работает передаваемый параметр index в Points, а также, что выполняет данная строчка:

```
double xval = chart1.Series["Price"].Points[index-1].XValue + 1;
```

Речь идет о CandleStick Chart (свечной график для отрисовки биржевых данных). Буду признателен, если подкинете пару советов о том, что происходит в данном методе.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: это Windows Forms?

Comment: Да, верно. Windows Form